# Is there api for giving me a list of directions for traveling from city A to city B

Tags: python, maps, directions

So I have this python program that has input `longitude` `latitude` of City A and City B. Is there an api that could output a string of directions to get from City A to City B. Like an output like:

```
Turn right on South DeAnza Blvd and then make a turn........ This is your destination.
```

Could anyone give me any guidance? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro).

> The Google Directions API is a service that calculates directions
>   between locations using an HTTP request.

A simple example:

```
import urllib2
import json

url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
j = json.loads(response.read())

for step in j['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps']:
    print step['html_instructions']
```

outputs:

```
Head <b>north</b> on <b>Bay St</b> toward <b>Hagerman St</b>
Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>Dundas St W</b>
Turn <b>left</b> onto the <b>Don Valley Parkway</b> ramp Merge onto <b>Don Valley Pkwy N</b>
Take the <b>ON-401 E</b> exit Merge onto <b>Ontario 401 Express</b>
Merge onto <b>ON-401 E</b>
Keep <b>left</b> at the fork to continue on <b>ON-401</b>
Continue onto <b>Autoroute du Souvenir/Autoroute 20</b>
<div style="font-size:0.9em">Entering Québec</div>
Keep <b>left</b> to continue on <b>Boulevard Ville-Marie/Autoroute 720 E</b>
Keep <b>right</b> to stay on <b>Boulevard Ville-Marie/Autoroute 720 E</b>
Take exit <b>4</b> toward <b>Rue de la Montagne N/Rue Saint-Jacques</b>
Turn <b>left</b> onto <b>Jean d'Estrees St</b>
Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>St Antoine St W</b>
Turn <b>left</b> onto <b>Rue Mansfield</b>
Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>René-Lévesque Blvd W</b>
Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>Boulevard Robert-Bourassa</b>
<div style="font-size:0.9em">Destination will be on the right</div>
```

Comment: Your code works only from Toronto to Montreal. I have input from Address A and input from Address B, and I need directions to go from A to B.

Comment: Do you know how to have customized origins and destinations in the code?

Comment: @TheAndruino: The code is just an example. You should modify it as you need. Please read the linked documentation in the answer.

Comment: How would I convert a latitude and longitude into a placeID?